# Decode the array values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to decode array values for passing it into json. I want to pass the values in contentvalue baaed on content type into json. Now It shows null. I want to move array value as **$zip_num=$content->zip;** based on content type.

[image]

```
 while ($ee = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $key_val = $ee['CONTENT_TYPE'];
   $content = json_decode($ee['CONTENT_VALUE']);
   if ($key_val == 'stat_sum') {
        $stat = $content;
    }
   if ($key_val == 'zip_stats') {
        $zip[] = $content;
        $zip_num=$content->zip;
        $zip_cou=$content->count;    
    }
    if ($key_val == 'qual_stats') {
        $qual[] = $content;
    }
 }
$new = array('ID'=>$id,'zip'=>$zip_num);
echo $json = json_encode($new);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$key_val` (that one which is in `if` statement) with `$ee['CONTENT_TYPE']`